# Setting the server to look for index.php file by default

Tags: php, root, cgi

I am a web developer and I've requested our Sys-Admin to setup a server for my team that will be used as a development environment.

The PHP is running as a CGI. When i try to open **http://myaddress/** I receive *403 Forbidden*. When I try to open **http://myaddress/index.php** everything is fine.

How do I set the server to look for index.php file by default?

*P.S The sysadmin is not currently here, so he cannot do it for me.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or put it into /etc/apache2/httpd.conf somewhere, but remember to comment old directive (i.e. index.html). On Windows file is located somewhere else.

Comment: It will be globally set.

Answer (score 4):

Use the DirectoryIndex directive:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Here's more info on [how to use DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).

Answer (score 3):

If you use Apache and have no access to it's configuration you can place .htaccess file inside web site folder.

Just put following content in file .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```